# R: Find max value for column among a subset of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, max, subset, plyr

I have a dataframe `df` with columns `ID`, `Year`, `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3` and 21788928 rows. I need to subset the data by `Year` and `ID`and find the max `Value1` in that subset saving the rest of information of that row, I need to do that for all the combinations of `Year` and `ID`(Year goes from 1982 to 2013,
ID is from 1 to 28371)

I was trying to do that in a double for loop:

```
year<-seq(1982, 2013)
cnt=1
for (i in 1:32) {
  for (j in 1:28371)

    A<-df[df$Year==year[i]&df$ID==j,] 
    maxVal[cnt,]<-A[A$Value1==max(A$Value1),]
    cnt=cnt+1
}
}
```

but it takes way to long. Is there a more efficient way to do that? Maybe using `ddply` or `with`.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data, and the desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(ID, Year) %>%
  summarise(mval=max(Value1)) -> result
```

or `plyr`, keeping all the other columns (and repeating max Value1 as `mval`)

```
ddply(dat, .(ID, Year), function(x) {
    transform(x[which.max(x$Value1),], mval=Value1)
  }, .drop=F)
```

---

**Data**

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=sample(1:10, 100, rep=T),
                  Year=sample(1995:2000, 100, rep=T),
                  Value1=runif(100))
```

Comment: Thank you! It did exactly what I wanted i just few min.

Comment: Or `library(data.table);setDT(dat)[, list(mval= max(Value1)) , .(ID, Year)]`

Answer (score 5):

A base R solution with `aggregate`:

```
prov <- aggregate(. ~ Year + ID, data = dat, FUN = max)
```

Comment: @Liza you are welcome. Consider to accept the answer that fits your goals and next time if you have to add clarifications please do edit your post and do not post an answer (unless of course you find by yourself the solution for your problems )